# The functions and variables generated by flex start with yy, how to change them to start with other letters

Tags: c, bison, lex

For example,the default is "yytext",but I want to rename it to "aatext",how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the Flex manual would be the natural place to look.  Google offers several versions of *Lexical Analysis with Flex*, for various versions of Flex.  For example, https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/.

The manual has a nice table of contents, which lists a chapter "Scanner options", which sounds promising, and a section within named "[Code-Level and API Options](https://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html#Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options)", which seems like it would be just the thing.

And Lo! In that section we can find documented the `prefix` option, which can be spelled `-PPREFIX` or `--prefix=PREFIX` on the Flex command line, or `%option prefix="PREFIX"` in the input file, and which

> changes the default 'yy' prefix used by flex for all globally-visible variable and function names to instead be 'PREFIX'.

Do read the rest of the documentation for that option, too.